# What do the crossed out intellisense's mean in VSCode?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I did have a quick search but couldn't find it anywhere. I have provided an image of what I mean. I mostly notice it on

```
-webkit-appearnce:
```

it seems to be crossed out in VSCode for some reason, what does this mean?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When hovering over the css attribute it states: `Property is nonstandard. Avoid using it.` So by crossing it out VsCode tells you, that is a possible option but it's discouraged to use. Just like deprecated features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I t means it's an experimental technology.
You might find this messages on some properties in the MDN docs:

> This is an experimental technology.
>
> Check the Browser compatibility
> table carefully before using this in production.

also

> Compatibility note: If you wish to use this property on websites, you
> should test it very carefully. Although it is supported in most modern
> browsers, its implementation varies widely. In older browsers, even
> the keyword none does not have the same effect on all form elements
> across different browsers, and some do not support it at all. The
> differences are smaller in the newest browsers.

It's there (the strike through) to warn you that this is an experimental feature or that it's **not** fully compatible

link: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance](http://%20developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance)

Comment: Hi Roy, can you provide a link to the MDN doc?

Comment: It's generally on some properties, like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

Comment: @Mac Hooper Glad to help you! Please consider marking this as accepted if it solved your problem so that other people can know it's helpful, thanks too.

Comment: Have done so, tried before and it said I had to wait five minutes.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about it

Comment: You can edit your answer and add the MDN link to the text

Comment: I added the link :)